# EditText background image fills parent

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have `EditText` view like this:

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:background="@drawable/writting_field"
    android:text="@string/test" />
```

But it stretches and fills parent. What is the problem?

Comment: Please clarify you need!! Try this: android:scaleType="center" or change its attribute which fits your need.

Comment: problem may be the background image..

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be Image size will be bigger enough so it occupying like FILL_PARENT.
To get override this , use 9Patch images. So that it takes as much size as of the Text.

Comment: the image size is bigger, i used nine patch but the result is the same

Comment: Don't use bigger image if u r using 9Patch, b'coz 9patch can stretch as your text will increase...

Answer (score 0):

If image size is same or bigger than parent it will automatically takes that much size , to take it fixed height width either you have to give it fixed height width in dp or try with ems option in edittext .